# String.Format() Hex with leading zero doesn't work for second argument

Tags: c#, string.format

I'm facing a weird issue with `String.Format()`. I need to format two hexadecimal numbers with leading zeroes to pad up to 8 digits. However, it works only for the first argument (`{0:X8}`). For the second argument (`{1:X8}`), only "X8" is printed.

This is my code:

```
public struct DataDirectory
{
    public uint VirtualAddress
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    public uint Size
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{{VirtualAddress=0x{0:X8},Size=0x{1:X8}}}", VirtualAddress, Size);
    }
}
```

The debugger output prints this:

[image: Debugger output]

EDIT: It seems to work if I remove the curly braces at the start and end of the format string, but then I'm missing those in the strings returned from `ToString()` (the debugger still adds those to the QuickWatch window):

```
return String.Format("VirtualAddress=0x{0:X8},Size=0x{1:X8}", VirtualAddress, Size);
```

Is it possible to format two hexadecimal numbers with `String.Format()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful with all those closing braces `}}}`.
You can use a separate format item for it, as in `Size=0x{1:X8}{2}`. So:

```
String.Format("{{VirtualAddress=0x{0:X8},Size=0x{1:X8}{2}", 
  VirtualAddress, Size, "}"
  )
```

The problem with `{1:X8}}}` is that it is not clear which double `}}` is an escaped `}`, and which single `}` is closing the item. The parser actually called `Size.ToString("X8}")` which was not what you intended.

Now you are going in that direction, maybe do:

```
String.Format("{2}VirtualAddress=0x{0:X8},Size=0x{1:X8}{3}", 
  VirtualAddress, Size, "{", "}"
  )
```

Comment: I think I get now what you mean. `String.Format()` seems to detect the first two closing curly braces at `{0x{1:X8_}}_}` as an escaped one, and the last one loses any meaning.
Accordint to your solution with replacing them, wouldn't that give me _two_ closing curly braces? I actually just wanted one (since they told me `}}` becomes just `}` in the string).

Comment: @DebugErr You are exactly right. `Size.ToString("X8}")` is seen as a custom format string instead of a standard format string. The returned string becomes the result of that item and is `"X8}"` no matter what value `Size` has. I tried to improve my answer several times.

Comment: I see. It took me some time to get it, as I thought the parser reads an opening curly brace (-> argument start) and the next closing one would be a the arguments end, since closing curly braces are not allowed inside argument formats, as far as I know. Obviously that's not the case. I think it's a bit dumb this way, but there might be cases where this behavior is more correct.

Comment: Here is a [MSDN String.Format Q & A](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#QA) where they recommend separate format items for literal braces. And here is [MSDN Custom numeric format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to understand what format `"X8}"` comes to mean.

Comment: Good article, some recommendations I can rely on. `X8}` also makes a good smiley, btw.